# How can i delete row from database in uitableviewcell using fmdb

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Can anyone help me how to delete row from database in uitableviewcell using fmdb.

I mean i wrote query about delete in datamanager.m as -(void) deleteTodo; it's working and shown in console as deleted the row.  But i wanna delete row in iphone simulator when i press Edit button.

How can i call that -(void) deleteTodo in Datamanger.m class.

My code is.......

```
-(void) deleteTodo
{
    [dataBase executeUpdate:@" delete from todo where pk='8'"];
    NSLog(@"Deleted");

}
```

But how can i use it in rootviewcontroller.m at commitEditingStyle Method. to delete row.

Please Help me....

Than

Comment: you may need to edit your post by making your codes nicely. Just add 4 spaces before your codes, and it will show up in a code layout.

Answer (score 0):

You should code as follows,

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle 
            forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
   {
       // If row is deleted, remove it from the list.
       if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) 
       {
           [dataSource removeDataAtIndex:indexPath.row];
           [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] 
                    withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
           // Create obj for the class DAtamanager
           DataManager *obj= [[DataManager alloc] init];
           [obj deleteTodo];
           [obj release];
       }

   }
```

Comment: You are welcome. Welcome to SO. Try to accept answers if it solves your solution. :)

Comment: Can u pls send total code for  Todo App using FMDB .. i.e inserting and updating also same as deleting ...